# using DOM operation in watch with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I've been trying to use document.getElementById("hoge").style.color in watch section but it doesn't work fine. The code below gets executed with selected_title_color1 gets changed and then, adds titleColor1 into p-modal's style. I'm sure titleColor1 gets value as I want but document.getElementById("p-modal").style.color = titleColor1 looks no working.

```js
data () {
    return {
      colors:['紅色','藍色','黃色','粉色','土地色','水藍色','灰色','淺綠色','橙色'],
      colors_dic:{紅色:'red',藍色:'blue',黃色:'yellow',粉色:'pink',土地色:'blawn',水藍色:'aqua',灰色:'gray',淺綠色:'palegreen',橙色:'orange'},
      selected_title_color1:'',
    }
}
watch:{
    selected_title_color1: function () {
      var titleColor0 = this.selected_title_color1;
      var titleColor1 = this.colors_dic[titleColor0];
      console.log(titleColor1)
      document.getElementById("p-modal").style.color = titleColor1
    }
  },
```

Comment: If you're using Vue.js and the DOM api at the same time, you're doing it wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Class and Style Bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) to achieve this as follows:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      colors: ['紅色', '藍色', '黃色', '粉色', '土地色', '水藍色', '灰色', '淺綠色', '橙色'],
      colors_dic: {
        紅色: 'red',
        藍色: 'blue',
        黃色: 'yellow',
        粉色: 'pink',
        土地色: 'blawn',
        水藍色: 'aqua',
        灰色: 'gray',
        淺綠色: 'palegreen',
        橙色: 'orange'
      },
      selected_title_color1: '',
      titleColor1: '',
    }
  },
  watch: {
    selected_title_color1: function() {
      this.titleColor1 = this.colors_dic[this.selected_title_color1];
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  Select Color:
  <select v-model="selected_title_color1">
    <option v-for="color in colors" :value="color">{{color}}</option>
  </select>
  <br/><br/>
  <span :style="{ color : titleColor1  }">Toggle the dropdown to change the text color...</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your friendly advice . I will use Style binding. It looks so handy.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "ref" for accessing to dom element in Vue:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div ref="test">
      test
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Test',
  data () {
    return {
      test: 'test'
    }
  },
  watch: {
    test () {
      const colors = [
        'red',
        'green',
        'blue',
        'purple',
        'pink'
      ]

      this.$refs.test.style.color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```